# Python MySQLdb error

Tags: python, mysql

When I run my script it won't connect to mysql database, I can't find my host name from godaddy I just tried mysq.mydomain.com and mydomain.com. the login details for the database are correct.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysql.py", line 6, in <module>
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="?",user="?",passwd="?",db="?")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'official_autotes'@'104.156.228.189' (using password: YES)")


------------------
```

my code

```
from threading import Thread
import urllib
import re
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="?",user="?",passwd="?",db="?")

query = "INSERT INTO tutorial (symbol) values ('AAPL')"
x = conn.cursor()
x.execute(query)
row = x.fetchal()
```

Comment: What about try to use `mysql` command in shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grand privilage to the user and ip trying to access the MySQL table using the Python code. To do the same, execute the following commands in the mysql shell.

```
GRANT <privileges> ON database.* TO 'user'@'ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
flush privileges;
```